# How can I get the Check box seleted Listview value in android?

Tags: android, checkbox, selection

I am displaying the check-box with Android List-view in the screen. Now I want to get the value of the list-item based on check-box selection. How can I do it?

Comment: ------------------------- 
 [CB]    TV            TV
-------------------------

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141124/android-listview-checkbox-selection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417339/android-listview-with-checkbox-and-all-clickable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834723/checkbox-in-listview-for-multiple-selection-of-contacts

Answer (score 1):

Check out tutorial of listview with checkbox you will get the idea of getting the values of checked item. [Link](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html)

Comment: i am displaying the check box and list . i want get the value of the selected checkbox ?

Comment: You mean to say that your checkbox and listview both are separate from eachother and you want to get the value of the list based on the checkbox selection ? I am sorry but m confused with your question. Can you please brief out/

Comment: yes ur understanding is correct i want get the listvalue based on checkbox selection?

Comment: @user1802043 In checkBox state changed() change the value of the listItem